# Cannot install package Rmysql

Tags: r, rmysql

When I try the following command

```
install.packages('RMySQL',type='source')
```

I got an error as below

```
Installing into ‘C:/Users/Thanushiya/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
trying URL 'http://ftp.iitm.ac.in/cran/src/contrib/RMySQL_0.10.6.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 52407 bytes (51 KB)
downloaded 36 KB

Error in untar2(tarfile, files, list, exdir, restore_times) : 
  incomplete block on file

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘C:\Users\Thanushiya\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpSMF6pv\downloaded_packages’
Warning messages:
1: In download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) :
  downloaded length 36864 != reported length 52407
2: running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.2/bin/i386/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Thanushiya\Documents\R\win-library\3.2" C:\Users\THANUS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpSMF6pv/downloaded_packages/RMySQL_0.10.6.tar.gz' had status 1 
3: In install.packages("RMySQL", type = "source") :
  installation of package ‘RMySQL’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: Did you try with another mirror? Do you have any antivirus running?

Comment: ya,  I tied India mirror only from HTTP mirror..isthat any problem? I installed Avg antivirus on my PC?is it give any trouble??

Comment: 1) Mirror could have a problem  2) yes, many reports on installation problem while an antivirus is running on Windows.

Comment: can you suggest me which will be good for this one?do i wantto stop running antivirus task?